# How to convert wav file to amr in javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio, wav, recorder, amr

Basically I want to record an audio. I am using [recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/) library which gives me blob data for wav file and i am converting it into a local 'audio.wav' file and storing it on device.

Now I want to convert it into amr format. For that I used [amrnb.js](http://yxl.github.io/opencore-amr-js/) which converts wav to amr and returns samples.

Now how samples can be converted into a file ?

Or else is there any way to record audio directly in amr format in recorderjs with low sampling rate and bitrate ?

Thank you.